# Scala <-> C and Scala <-> Rust interoperability. How?

Tags: c, rust

How can I call a method from C library from Scala?
The same question for a library written not in C, but in Rust.
Are there examples?

And are there ways to do it **directly**? Namely, without intermediate wrapper in Java, or without C wrapper in case of Rust library. But this way

```
Scala <-> C lib
Scala <-> Rust lib
```

And if not, how to do it at least indirectly?

Comment: Have you read about `#[no_mangle]` attribute?

Comment: Maybe **ScalaNative** or **GraalVM** can help.

Comment: See also [The Rust FFI Omnibus](http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/). No one has contributed Java / JVM languages yet, but it's all the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can do lot of things to be honest:

- use scalaNative (https://github.com/scala-native/scala-native)
- use java libraries like `JNA` (https://github.com/java-native-access/jna)
- or use GraalVM (https://www.graalvm.org/)

each option has its own limitations and they are not compatible with each others.